# uno letro y otro titulo separa en el css

Tags: css

tengo mal codigo de css , 2 span uno letra izquerdo y otro título centero. 
css por cada uno

```css
.mt {
  border: 1px solid#000;
  width: 350px;
  
}

.mtitle {
  background: #007281;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mdesc {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mt">
  
  <div class="mtitle">
    <span>A.</span><span>FOCOS DE INNOVACIÓN</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mdesc">
    es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto.
  </div>

</div>
```

sino un div, pero con display inline

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres separarlos, letra  y título?

Comment: @Carmen Si como maqueta

Comment: Te pongo respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolverlo podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- A `mtitle` indicarle que el texto dentro este centrado [(`eg: text-align: center`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).
- Crear una nueva clase, por ejemplo `mchar` y hacer que flote a la izquierda [(`eg: float:left`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) y asignarsela al `span` que contiene la letra `A`

Así por ejemplo:

```css
.mt {
  border: 1px solid#000;
  width: 350px;
}
.mtitle {
  background: #007281;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.mchar {
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.mdesc {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mt">
  <div class="mtitle">
    <span class="mchar">A.</span>
    <span>FOCOS DE INNOVACIÓN</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mdesc">
    es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu explicarme.

Answer (score 2):

Al tener las etiquetas spam puedes asignarles directamente clases css

```css
.mt {
  border: 1px solid#000;
  width: 350px;
  
}

.mtitle {
  background: #007281;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
}

.mdesc {
  padding: 10px;
} 
.big, .ml {display: inline;}
.big{ font-size: 25px; width: 10%; float: left;}
.ml {width: 88%; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="mt">
  
  <div class="mtitle">
    <div class="big">A.</div><div class="ml">FOCOS DE INNOVACIÓN</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mdesc">
    es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto.
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: esta bien gracias pero class ml puede text-center y no margin-left y mejor text-center porque otra letra y otros titulos largos y cortos

Comment: No se va a aplicar en el spam , tendrías que ponerlo en el div dentro del cual está el spam y afectaría a los dos spam.  Puedes crear dos divs con display inline-block y el segundo con textalign center;

Comment: puedes editar tu codigo

Comment: Editado, ya lo tienes con divs.